# Minimum interior wall opening height

Tags: framing, windows, code-compliance, usa

I am going to build some interior walls that have openings that do **not** get windows, as far as I can tell, the minimum sill height off the floor is 24"; this seems awfully low as people could still fall through the opening.

What is the minimum sill height for an interior wall opening that does **not** get enclosed with glass.

This is in Washington State, USA.

Comment: For a wall opening to another room on the same level(no safety concern), then I think the size is more of a function form.  From dining to kitchen, then want a shelve/sill height  handy for handing dishes.

Comment: I'm confused. You are saying that you think the minimum sill height is "dangerously low". What keeps you from just making it higher?

Comment: @keshlam I didn't say 'dangerous", I said I thought it was awfully low. What keeps me from making it higher, the plans and owner approval, I would like to approach that conversation with as much knowledge as possible

Comment: Ah. So you're asking as builder rather than homeowner. That does explain, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That I am aware of, there is no minimum height. If there is a concern of falling through the opening, a guardrail can be added or raise the sill. If the conditions exist where the IRC code requires fall protection, raise the sill up to 36". The added guard rail can work too, by adding a 1' rail to th 24" tall sill. It could be lower, just make the rail top out at 36" at least. I prefer 38" myself.

Comment: And this may be a case of the homeowner not having or expecting to have toddlers in the house, who are the reason behind most minimum-height rules. If that changes then, yes, they can always reconsider and add a "decorative" railing. Remember, the customer isn't always right ... but the customer is the one with the money, and sometimes it's better to be paid than right.